# How to I set up Linux KVM to automatically assign VNC ports to guests

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I am setting up some guests on a Scientific Linux 6 box running KVM. I do the

> virsh vncdisplay machinename

command and it does not show me an assigned VNC port. How do I assign VNC ports to guests? I already edited the /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf file to have

> vnc_listen = "0.0.0.0"

I am simply looking how to assign VNC ports to guests. Setting this up to automatically assign VNC ports to new guests would be great as well.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. Needed to edit /etc/libvirt/qemu/vm.xml

Added this :

```
<graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' keymap='en-us'/>
```

Thanks to this article: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-kvm-vnc-for-guest-machine/